# How to mount VHD file with bootable linux USB

Tags: mount, xenserver, vhd, gparted

I have a Xenserver which the primary drive has failed to the point it won't boot.  However, my RAID containing the SRs is fine.  I can boot with gparted USB stick and mount the RAID LVM and see the .VHD files.  However, I don't know which VHDs I actually need (only a couple VMs are important on this server).

Any way I can mount the VHD files (without copying them to USB and carrying to another computer, due to VERY slow transfer to USB)?

I tried installing virtualbox-fuse inside the gparted environment, but apt-get can't find the package. I also tried grabbing the .deb directly but it depends on virtualbox, which depends on a gazillion other packages.

Thx for any help.

Comment: chroot to the root partition on raid, then you have an installed working virtualbox.